# Checking if array isSorted using Recursion in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, recursion

In the below code i am trying to check if the array is sorted in ascending order using recursion;But have a few doubts:

1. I dont understand why we use arr[0] and arr[1] in place of using arr[i] and arr[i+1].
2. I understand why we would pass arr+1, but why are we reducing the size of array using size-1 ? shouldnt this result in the nth part of the array to be reduced ?

```
bool isSorted(int *arr, int size){
  if(size == 0 || size == 1){
    return true;
  }
  //compare two adjacent elements and reduce the size
  if(arr[0] > arr[1]){
    return false;
  }

  bool ans = isSorted(arr+1, size-1);
  return ans;
}
```

Comment: Do you have to use recursion ?

Comment: from where did you take the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case `int *arr` is not an array, it's pointer to the some element of the array. And `arr[0]` means this element, `arr[1]` means next element after `*arr`. `arr[i] <=> *(arr + i)`. U can easily do something like that:
`int *p = arr[5];` and now p[0] and arr[5] are the same things.
So in the first step `arr` looks at the first element and compares first and second. On next step `arr` looks at the second element and compares second and third etc. And u have to understand a distance between current element and end of array that's why you decrease size

Comment: So that means if is pass int arr[] in the function isSorted, it will have a different meaning ?

Comment: Depends on how u created array in the past. There are 2 ways to create an array, on stack like `int arr[5]` and on heap like `int *arr = new int[n]` where n - variable. In the first case arr will be an array and u will be able to get it's size by sizeof(). In the second way arr will be just a pointer on the first element of that array in the heap. I don't know how u created an array before but in both cases if u send arr to this function, in function scope arr will be just a pointer to the first element of array

Comment: @abcdefgh No it doesn't mean that. As a parameter `int arr[]` is exactly the same as `int* arr`. It's actually **impossible** to have an array as a parameter in C++, it's always a pointer. Understanding the relationship between arrays and pointers is pretty much essential before you can understand this code.

Comment: @Cycxyz No that's a pointer as well. In that function try finding out what the value of `sizeof(t)` is, you will find that it's the size of a pointer, not the size of an array.

Comment: @Cycxyz then as per ur ans, arr[0] and arr[1] basically means what the array points to ? and it is not the 0th index and 1st index elements in the array as i thought it was ?

Comment: @abcdefgh What the *pointer* points to, but yes you are correct.

Comment: @john Yea, my fault

Comment: @abcdefgh Exactly